# Retrieving Data from mysql table and manipulating them

Tags: mysql

I have following table

[image]

---

record which have same record Id has same company_ID with different fertilizer ID s.I want to retrieve data in following structure.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Look into `pivoting` that's what you need here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below query, if you face any issue then create a sqlfiddle so that I can check and correct it.

```
SELECT record_id, entry_time, company_id, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(quantity ORDER BY `no`),',',1) AS fertilizer_id_1, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(quantity ORDER BY `no`),',',2),',',-1) AS fertilizer_id_2, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(quantity ORDER BY `no`),',',-1) AS fertilizer_id_3 
FROM mytable 
WHERE record_id=company_id 
GROUP BY record_id;
```

Comment: It works as I want when I delete WHERE record_id=company_id because I mean all the  rows which have records_ID 5 should be belong to same company may be company 1 or 2. its my mistake. Anyway thank you very much